# Any way to clear selections from features in a map only if they have selected features?

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute, iteration

While I know the clear selection tool exists in ArcMap, I am looking to produce a script that would only work if all selections are cleared from the start. I have added lines of code to clear selections from each of the layers in my map but that adds about a minute to my whole process. Which makes me wonder, is there a way I could say for example:

```
if fc has selected features:
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(fc, "CLEAR_SELECTION")
else:
    pass
```

Obviously that isn't it but something similar maybe? That iterates through the map document for layers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, each [Layer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/layer-class.htm) has a method called `getSelectionSet()`, which returns a list of selected OIDs for the layer.

```
>>> for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
...     if lyr.isFeatureLayer and lyr.getSelectionSet():
...         print 'clearing {} selected features for layer: "{}"'.format(len(lyr.getSelectionSet()), lyr.name)
...         # clear selection
...         arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute(lyr, 'CLEAR_SELECTION')
...     else:
...         pass # or do something else
...         
clearing 4 selected features for layer: "Morningdrive_GPXtoFeatures"
clearing 5 selected features for layer: "DriveTrack"
>>>
```

Comment: While you're using `gerSelectionSet()` you could possibly also use `setSelectionSet()` to clear it by passing an empty set. If it works (this is untested as I'm commenting from my phone) this will possibly be much faster than calling the select layer by attribute to clear it.

Comment: Ah yes, I think that would work.  I haven't tested either but the `setSelectionSet()` supports a selection type and an input list of Object Ids.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could count the number of features selected by using the FIDSet property of the layers/features as done here: (see the code sample at the bottom of this page http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/describe.htm). Then you could use the count in your "has selected features" logic.

```
...
layerString = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
desc = arcpy.Describe(layerString)
...
if desc.FIDSet != '':
    print("Number of selected features: {}".format(len(desc.FIDSet.split(";"))))
```